# performance issue with nested for loops

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop

I have a nested for loop that performs some calculations and the math has been simplified to a great extent, however I still have a performance issue that I'm not sure I can resolve.  I don't believe it can be resolved due to the sheer number of times these for loops execute.  Now I'm not familiar with using any analytical tools to help determine where the slow downs occur within these but I am fairly certain that it's just the number of times these loops execute.

I would greatly appreciate any help in helping trim this down and increase the performance of this code.  I'm trying to stay away from a HPC or highly parallelized solution, but if that's the only way to make this truly effective then I'll look into going down that road.

Here's the code with X= 20,000 and N_zero= 45,420 (values pulled from actual tests):

```
Dictionary<decimal, int> n_alpha = new Dictionary<decimal, int>();
Random rand = new Random();
decimal r = 0m;
decimal check=0m;

for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    B = N_0 = N_1 = N0_ = N1_ = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < N_zero; j++)
    {
        // need a random decimal value between 0 and 1
        r = (decimal)rand.Next() / int.MaxValue;
        if (r <= r1)
        {
            N0_ += 1;
            N_0 += 1;
        }
        else if (r1 < r && r <= r2)
        {
            B += 1;
            N0_ += 1;
            N_1 += 1;
        }
        else if (r2 < r && r <= r3)
        {
            B += 1;
            N_0 += 1;
            N1_ += 1;
        }
        else if (r > r3)
        {
            N1_ += 1;
            N_1 += 1;
        }

    }
    check = N_0 * N_1 * N0_ * N1_;
    if (check != 0)
    {
        decimal a = 1 - (B * N_zero) / ((N_0 *N1_) + (N0_ *  N_1 ));
        // technically only tracking 4 decimal points, so key should reflect this
        decimal key = Math.Round(a, 4);
        if (n_alpha.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            n_alpha[key] += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            n_alpha.Add(key, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish.  If the loops are too slow, the likely solution to speed it up is to redesign the logic to accomplish both your functional goal and performance goal.  Just seeing some numbers float around it's really hard to tell what this should output.

Comment: I think you're looking for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If precision is not needed you could change the decimal types to float and you don't mind some rounding errors.

Comment: what are the values for r1, r2 and r3?

Comment: I have tested it, if you remove the Random generation it halfs the execution time, may be you can use a faster random algorithm.

Comment: Dictionary can also be surprisingly heavy when used in tight loops.

Comment: @Gilles `decimal` is not immune to rounding errors. It just changes what kind of rounding errors occur.  There's not enough context in this case to know for sure, but I agree that using `decimal` is likely inappropriate in this case (and would probably be a fairly significant cause of the poor performance).

Comment: There are a great many oddities in this code which are suspicious. Rather than pointing out all of them at length, **learn to use a profiler**.  Performance problems can only be consistently solved with *empirical measurements*. Set a goal, measure performance, compare it to your goal, find the slowest thing, try to fix it, and repeat until you're done.  **Strangers on the internet cannot reliably tell you where the code is slow**.

Comment: That said, the most obvious thing to speed up this code is to use doubles, not decimals. Can you say why you chose decimal over double? Are these financial computations?

Comment: As an aside, I reimplemented this code as given using doubles (or ints where appropriate) and the version using doubles executes almost 14 times faster (it finishes in ~19 seconds compared to almost 4 and a half minutes for the code given).  It also resulted in the same output given the same random seed.

Comment: You said you are trying to avoid parallelization, but it would be simple to change the outer for loop to a Parallel.For(). If you do, be sure to put a lock() around the final if...else.

Comment: You can simplify your `if`/`else` logic. If `r` is not `<= r1` then the second `if` could make the extreme leap of `r1 < r` without explicitly checking. And so on through the `if`s. Such is the miracle of `else`.

Comment: Assuming that `key` is between 0 and 1 (to 4 decimal places) it may be more efficient to use an array instead of a dictionary.

Comment: @HABO Based on my tests the keys in the dictionary can be negative (and their range doesn't seem to be well-defined).

Comment: @EricLippert these are statistical computations.  so accuracy was foremost in mind when attempting this.  also I'll look into using a profiler, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Kyle   if doubles will reduce computation time by that much, then I guess doubles will be a major improvement.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Do not think of doubles as *inaccurate*. They are *extremely accurate*. They *have representation error for most quantities that are exact decimals*.  Just as decimals have representation error for most quantities that are *not* exact decimals. **The fact that you are rounding to four places indicates to me that you don't actually care about accuracy that much**.

Comment: The rule is to use decimals *when you must consistently represent exact decimal quantities*. That is: financial computations. Use doubles to represent physical or statistical quantities. If you think it is odd to be charged `$123.44999999999999999999999`, you should have used decimals instead of doubles. If you think that it is perfectly sensible for a computation to say that you are `123.449999999999999999999` centimeters tall and you're OK with rounding that to the nearest millimeter, then use doubles.

Comment: This loops apprx. 900,000,000 times.  How long does it take now, and how fast does it need to be?

Answer (score 0):

1. The use of `rand.Next()` is a bit of a performance problem.  If you can live with a home-brewed, quick and dirty [*Linear Congruential Generator*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3062783/773113) you will be much better off.
2. The use of `decimal` is also a major performance problem.  Do not use `decimal` if you can avoid it.  Use `double` instead.
3. The use of `Dictionary` can also be a bit of a problem, especially if the distribution of your data is such that it causes lots of hash collisions.  I do not know what the range of your numeric data is, nor how it is distributed in that range, but if you can replace the dictionary with an array, by all means, do it.
4. You may be able to completely eliminate your inner nested loop.  Since `rand.Next()` supposedly yields numbers with a uniform distribution, and since `r1`, `r2` and `r3` are known in advance and do not change in the loops, you can simply calculate how many `r`s would be issued that are below `r1`, how many many `r`s would fall between `r1` and `r2`, etc. without actually issuing any `r`s.  So, just add the corresponding quantities to your `N0`, `N_1`, etc instead of adding `1` each time.

**EDIT** Clarification about #4:

So, judging by the way you issue `r`, it can have values from `0.0` to `1.0`. (Inclusively or exclusively doesn't really matter.)  So, I presume that `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` are also between `0.0` and `1.0`.  Therefore, assuming a perfectly uniform distribution, your `r`s should be as follows:

- `r < r1` will occur `N_Zero * r1` times
- `r1 < r < r2` will occur `N_Zero * (r2 - r1)` times
- `r2 < r < r3` will occur `N_Zero * (r3 - r2)` times
- `r3 < r` will occur `N_Zero * (1 - r3)` times.

Comment: How would you pre-determine how many r's would be issued for each of the checks? I'm looking into utilizing an array instead of the dictionary, but it'll take me some time to figure out how to handle the array and the indexes. Also with my requirements, I don't think the Linear Congruential Generator will work here, but I will keep it in mind and will do some testing.

Comment: @shadonar I amended my answer.